# Comment line between commands changes layout

Tags: macros, layout

Can someone explain to me what goes on behind the scenes here? I thought latex does ignore empty lines...

I have the following command defined

```
\newcommand{\requirement}[3]{
        \textcolor{blue}{#1 \hfill SysReq-{#2}}\\
        \textcolor{blue}{\rule{\textwidth}{1.0pt}}
        {#3}
        \vspace{\belowdisplayskip}
}
```

If I use it like this

```
    \requirement{Test 3}{3}{
        This is some requirement text defined with the command. Let's make it a bit longer so it spans more than one line of text.
    }

    \requirement{Test 4}{4}{
        This is some other requirement text defined with the command.
    }
```

everything is fine
[image]

but if I add a comment line between the two (instead of a blank line) they are squezeed into one another.

[image]

What is the job of the empty line between the two commands?

Comment: Empty line = (usually) `\par` = new paragraph = no squeezing. If you have time, consult a basic tutorial for LaTeX.

Comment: Put a `\par` in front of `\vspace` in your definition and you'll get the expected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\vspace` is a LaTeX wrapper around the two TeX primitives `\vskip` and `\vadjust`: `\vskip` inserts vertical glue, and starts vertical mode when encountered in horizontal mode, while `\vadjust` inserts vertical material in horizontal mode.

In your current definition, `\vspace` is encountered in horizontal mode (unless you manually start a new paragraph in the third argument of your macro) and therefore the `\vadjust` branch is executed. Not leaving a blank line between the two consecutive calls of `\requirement` therefore causes the result you observe.

To solve this problem just introduce a `\par` before `\vspace`. I've introduced another couple of improvements (?).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\requirement}[3]{%
   \par\noindent
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
   \color{blue}%
   \leavevmode\ignorespaces#1 \hfill SysReq-\ignorespaces#2\\
   \rule[1ex]{\textwidth}{1.0pt}%
   \end{minipage}%
   \par\nobreak\@afterheading
   \noindent\ignorespaces#3
   \par\vspace{\belowdisplayskip}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\requirement{Test 1}{1}{% <-- Not necessary since I've used \ignorespaces
   This is some requirement text defined with the command.
   Let's make it a bit longer so it spans more than one line of text.
}

\requirement{Test 2}{2}{%
   This is some requirement text defined with the command.
   Let's make it a bit longer so it spans more than one line of text.
}
\requirement{Test 3}{3}{%
   This is some requirement text defined with the command.
   Let's make it a bit longer so it spans more than one line of text.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've to go through this in detail but that's great, thanks!

Comment: @po.pe The part relevant to your question is the `\par`, as I've described. The rest are small changes to avoid spurious spaces and overfull lines, and to prevent page breaks at wrong places (that's the reason for putting the "header" into a `minipage` and for the strange code `\par\nobreak\@afterheading`). The optional `[1ex]` to `\rule` raises the rule a bit but that's my personal taste.